# Research in geophysics

Tags: undergraduate, research-undergraduate, independent-researcher

I am an undergraduate student in geophysics. I have read two types of papers in this  field.

First, the field work papers that shows survey results using some particular methods.

Second, paper in which novel advanced mathematical concepts are used to solve geophysics problem. 95% of mathematical stuff.

I have implemented some paper and have created a series of softwares for numerical studies, but there is nothing novel in that.

What should I do as an undergrad to enter the field of research in geophysics?

Comment: Are there research active geophysicists at your university?  Have you approached them and asked if there are any opportunities to participate in their research?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Yes, I know a prof very well, I asked him the same for which he told me to study more and find out problems on my own and solve them. But it seems quite impossible to come up with a novel idea on my own with a little knowledge and time left.

Answer (score 1):

If you have few research opportunities where you are, you could just defer serious research until grad school.  And concentrate on your current studies.

Maybe use the current undergrad time (if you are so advanced) to build a foundation in some advanced mechanics (from physics) or FMEA from mechE or some math techniques (probability and statistics, spectral analysis, advanced DEs, etc.)  The reason I say this is because once you are in the grad program, it can be hard to do things like this if you are diving into your particular research.

I would also urge you to develop yourself as a geoscientist overall.  Learn some more basic geology (the terminology is a zoo) or geochemistry (I find this stuff rock easy and interesting but many geoscientists are scared of chemistry).  If you are interested in oil exploration, it can be useful to know a but about petroleum engineering as well.  It's not what you do as a geophysicist, but really petroleum business is rather interdisciplinary and it the completion can be changed based on the geology.

Finally, you might consider to get some work experience if possible.  Ideally in geophysics but don't be picky. Anything in earth sciences.

(Just some ideas sparked by your post.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the US and not yet a senior, **consider applying for an [REU Fellowship](https://www.nsf.gov/crssprgm/reu/list_result.jsp?unitid=5050).** These are federally-funded research fellowships that you complete over the summer. This is a great way to get research experience. Research with a professor at your institution would also be good, but sounds like that has not worked out so far.

I also agree with guest that you should focus on coursework -- the more relevant coursework you can complete, particularly in physics, chemistry, and math, the better you will be suited for grad school.